# Can AnyObject be treated as normal objects ? How?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have AnyObject

```
    var currentObject : AnyObject
```

its value depends on if statement :

```
 if sender.tag == 1 { 
         currentObject = object1()
 }
else if sender.tag == 2 {
        currentObject = object2()
}
.....
etc
```

numberOfRowsInSection function:

```
   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
       return(currentObject.count)
    }
```

cellForRowAt function:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell 
    let p = currentObject.item[indexPath.row] 
    cell.textLabel?.text = p.something
    return(cell)
}
```

and I want to use this line at cellForRowAt function to retrieve cell content from different objects

```
let p = currentObject.item[indexPath.row]
```

I got an error says: 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSIndexPath'

I want my AnyObject to be treated as the object that I already assigned to it.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Please show more code; How is `currentObject` declared?

Comment: Do not use `AnyObject` or `Any` as a common type for objects you know the static type of. Use a protocol based solution to constrain the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are strongly discouraged from using that kind of approach.

**Use a protocol based solution.**

In your example both types are supposed to respond to `item` so declare a protocol

```
protocol HasItem {
    var items : [MyType] { get }
}
```

I'm using the plural form `items` as the type is an array.

---

Then adopt the protocol in your object classes

```
struct Object1 : HasItem {
    var items = [MyType]()
}

struct Object2 : HasItem {
    var items = [MyType]()
}
```

---

Now you can declare `currentObject` as `HasItem`

```
var currentObject : HasItem
```

---

Since the compiler knows that an object which conforms to `HasItem` has an `items` array this will compile flawlessly

```
let p = currentObject.items[indexPath.row]
```

---

The return value in `numberOfRowsInSection` is not logical. Most likely this is intended

```
return currentObject.items.count
```

And please be aware that `return` is **not** a function, there are no parentheses.

---

If you want to use other common properties and functions in the protocol type you have to add those to the protocol.

And if `MyType` could be also of different types use another protocol with a property `something`.

Answer (score 2):

`AnyObject` can be treated as a "base class" for all objects.

So if you have:

```
let index: AnyObject = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
```

You can use it by casting it to the desired type:

```
if let indexPath = index as? IndexPath {
   // indexPath is type of IndexPath
}
```

Not all `AnyObject` can be `IndexPath`, thats why the cast can fail.

This is really basic learning here. I Suggest you check out [A Swift Tour by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to as an Object is actually a Dictionary. Object is not something that exists in Swift in the way that you're thinking about.

That said, what you might want to do is cast your AnyObject as follows:

```
if let myDict = currentObject.item as? [AnyObject],
   let p = myDict[indexPath.row] {

   // p is now an AnyObject, cast to whatever you need again

}
```

Swift is a very strict language so you'll need to make sure that Swift always knows what type something is. Imagine this object:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "label": "hello world"
}
```

You would extract the id and label in Swift like this:

```
let myObject: [String: AnyObject] = // import the above object as you please
let label = myObject["label"] as? String // cast to string so Swift knows what the type of the label is
let id = myObject["id"] as? Int // must cast again so Swift knows the type of the id.
```

Hope this is of some help to you :)